# Nifi Provenance results display attributes

Tags: apache-nifi

We have requirement to be able to view and search Provenance Data with some pre-defined attributes.

The Search part was easily resolved by adding those attribute names to  `nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.attributes` property in `nifi.properties` file.

We are unable to find a way to display those attributes in the grid of Provenance Results Dialog.

Does someone have a way to configure/customize it? We are even willing to update Nifi source to allow this if someone can point us to the right place.

Comment: For a better long-term approach, you should look at using SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask to build a flow to deliver the Prov data to an external search tool e.g. Solr, Elastic. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.reporting.SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask/

Comment: Thanks for your input @Sdairs. It seemed to be a bit of an overkill for what I wanted to achieve. But I'll check it out if that's the only option available.